# Bash for MS-DOS?

Tags: bash, ms-dos

This question was ported from [Ask Ubuntu site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401121/bash-for-ms-dos).

---

According to GNU link to Bash developer:

> Bash is the shell, or command language interpreter, for the GNU operating system. The name is an acronym for the *Bourne-AgainSHell*, a pun on Stephen Bourne, the author of the direct ancestor of the current Unix shell *sh*, which appeared in the Seventh Edition Bell Labs Research version of Unix. ... While the GNU operating system provides other shells, including a version of *csh*, Bash is the default shell. Like other GNU software, Bash is quite portable. It currently runs on nearly every version of Unix and a few other operating systems - independently-supported ports exist for **MS-DOS**, OS/2, and Windows platforms.

I know about Windows platform support, which is currently done using WSL, which stands for Windows Subsystem for Linux, and it is essentially a virtual machine running Linux with a complete kernel under Windows. Terminal is then emulated through Windows Terminal app. Unless the literal Windows port is what was meant here, which is what I would like to see, too. The OS/2 port is basically Mac OS and similar, Apple produced systems, which is based on Unix, like Linux, so it does make sense to include Bash here. But what is the **MS-DOS** port? I never knew that there was an MS-DOS port, but couldn't find anything about it online.

DOS shell is completely different, it was developed by IBM, originally as proof of concept where they showed that personal computer can be used to manipulate with data with ease, following simple commands. No doubt that it was inspired by Unix shell, which is much older than DOS. The first commercial version of DOS was then produced by Microsoft, labeled as MS-DOS, and first versions didn't even support folder structures, just files. First MS-DOS compatible computers didn't even have hard disk drive, only floppy drives. Two floppy drives, one for system disk (MS-DOS), the other for data disks. System drive was labeled "A", data drive was labeled "B". Then hard disk was added and because drive letter "A" and "B" was already assigned to floppy disks, drive letter "C" was then chosen for permanent system storage disk, and this is history, and historically, drives in Windows are starting from "C" unless it's a floppy drive, that works even today.

I can't imagine Bash on MS-DOS, and I'd like to see it in action to be honest. I have an MS-DOS virtual machine, so **can you guys provide me some way to download the MS-DOS version of Bash**, so I can then then install it in my MS-DOS virtual machine and give it a try? Unless that refers to the actual command prompt of MS-DOS that started with inspiration from Unix shell, but rather quite difers in the ways it processes commands and with internal commands collection.

I'd also like to try out Norton Commanded on MS-DOS, but that's not the topic of this rather quite curious question.

---

What I forgot to mention in original question on Ask Ubuntu (where it was closed for off-topic), I have MS-DOS v6.22, for me most notable version. It's not the latest version, but it is the latest official version of MS-DOS. Later versions were included in Win32 environments.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: @Ramhound: There you go, fixed it :)

Comment: Bash for Windows exists. It’s distributed with Git for Windows, for example. I don’t see what would be so different on MS-DOS that it could not work.

Comment: I don't know if Git actually exists in version for MS-DOS, because Git was created much later when MS-DOS was no longer used as a main OS, and Git was originally purely just Unix tool. Bash does exist for a longer time, basically coexisting with MS-DOS.

Comment: @DanielB: _A lot_ is different between DOS and Windows. I don't think you can even create multiple processes for a pipeline in MS-DOS – from what I recall, Bash had to run the commands in series, using a temporary file on disk in place of the actual pipe (i.e. `a|b|c` becomes `a>tmp1; b<tmp1>tmp2; c<tmp2`).

Comment: Yeah, MS-DOS was a single process OS, it didn't support any kind of multitasking, so true pipelines were impossible in DOS. But temporary files were a possibility, so there is a workaround for this, but it's much, much slower and delayed. And to be honest, DOS despite being quite different from Unix, had some similarities. Like Unix based OS, it doesn't treat files based on their extension. In fact it does, but only for executables (.BAT, .COM and .EXE files in this particular order). Every other file type is ignored by the interpreter to be honest. And there's no tab complete, eighter.

Comment: > "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center." - Excuse me? Bash is a computer software, how is this not about that? I have a genuine problem that I couldn't find any version of Bash for MS-DOS, all I found was a general mention, and that's it. What exactly is off-topic here? Does it really matter? Answers were given, that's all I need now.

Comment: is the question worth moving to retrocomputing.stackexchange?

Comment: @jarnosz I don't know. Given the fact it has been answered already before the question got closed, I guess it's not necessary to move it. But I'm kinda intrigued what kind of answers I might get there, so I guess it might be okay to move it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MKS Toolkit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_Toolkit) was a distribution of various Unix tools ported to MS-DOS, including apparently Bash and the Korn shell.

> I know about Windows platform support, which is currently done using WSL, which stands for Windows Subsystem for Linux, and it is essentially a virtual machine running Linux with a complete kernel under Windows. Terminal is then emulated through Windows Terminal app. Unless the literal Windows port is what was meant here, which is what I would like to see, too.

The Windows port isn't referring to WSL, either – it is a native Win32 .exe application; there are several, such as the one that comes with Cygwin or the one from MSYS/MinGW (bundled with Git).

You don't need a Unix-like kernel to run a Unix shell. Unlike say DCL, the shell in Unix is a very ordinary program (not any different from e.g. Python REPL) and Windows has facilities that are *similar enough* to port things like pipelines.

> The OS/2 port is basically Mac OS and similar, Apple produced systems, which is based on Unix, like Linux, so it does make sense to include Bash here

No, IBM OS/2 has really nothing to do with neither OS X nor classic MacOS. (And the classic MacOS was *not* Unix-based; it was quite a different beast.)

Comment: I slso found https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJGPP which talks about - and has links to another toolkit that also compilrd BASH for DOS.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thank you. The MKS Toolkit Wikipedia page leads to the websites, but I can't see download for older systems, it even implies that the package download is paid. But thank you, this is a starting point I can explore. And please next time, if you copy links from mobile browser, edit it so it doesn't lead to mobile version of the site, Wikipedia automatically opens moble version on mobile devices even from links leading to desktop site version. Just remove the `.m` from the domain. It looks weird opening a mobile site on desktop, Wikipedia doesn't automate it other way around.

Comment: I can't edit your answer just to edit out the mobile indicator from the Wikipedia link, it tells me I have to do more extensive edits if there is something to improve. There is, but all it takes is just removing two characters, that's it. I can't do that, you'll have to edit it yourself. Not to mention I cannot eddit comments of others at all, you'll have to edit it as well @davidgo and user1686.

Comment: Although, I can't seem to find any mention about BASH on DJGPP site, but it may be just automatically implied by the "GNU programming platform", which should include Bash, too. I'm not sure tho. I guess it's not as exciting as it seemed to be at first glance. Anyways, thank you for your answer, marking it as accepted. I'm still going to figure out how to download the correct version for DOS and try it out, but I don't expect quite a good amount of excitement out of it. It sounds more exciting than it really seems to be after reading online sources. What got me excited was initial lack of them.

Comment: a follow up on djgpp: go to the website at http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/dl/ofc/dlfiles.cgi/current/v2gnu/ and download `bsh204*.zip`; beware it may need the runtime library `cwsdpmi.exe` for extended memory support. And this is REAL DOS, not the cmd on WinX.

Comment: are you sure the mks toolkit works on old ms-dos 6.22? are not you mistaking it for the cmd interface on windows?

Comment: @jarnosz That's what I was wondering. In Windows 9x, the command line was indeed the MS-DOS command prompt. Windows NT didn't have that, instead the command line was a DOS command prompt emulator instead. There was an MS-DOS environment emulator in 32bit Windows NT, it lacked some functions tho. Starting from Windows Vista, MS-DOS command prompt lacked support for graphical modes and lacked drivers for internal PC speaker.